# Pythagorean Triple in Haskell

Tags: haskell, math

I need to run a `Haskell`program in which I enter a number, and tell me the pythagorean triangles (a, b, c) so that 'a' is the number entered. This is it;

```
pythagoreanTriple :: Integer -> [(Integer, Integer, Integer)]

pythagoreanTriple 25 == [(25,60,65),(25,312,313)]

pythagoreanTriple 20 == [(20,15,25),(20,21,29),(20,48,52),(20,99,101)]
```

I've tried it this way, but it's very inefficient, because for low numbers it works, but when they ask for a high number it doesn't work.

```
 pythagoreanTriple :: Integer -> [(Integer, Integer, Integer)]

 pythagoreanTriple n = [(n,b,c) | c <- [2..n^2], b <- [2..c-1], n^2 + b^2 == c^2]
```

I need the function to work for `pythagoreanTriple 14578950150`, but I can't get it.

In case you don't know what a Pythagorean Triple is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple

**I've done the algorithm you told me, but it doesn't give the same results as the example, and it takes a long time.**

**SOLUTION**

```
pythagoreanTriple :: Integer -> [(Integer, Integer, Integer)]
pythagoreanTriple a = [(a,b,c) | c <- [a+1..(a^2+1) `div` 2]
                               , let b = (round . sqrt . fromIntegral) (c^2 - a^2)
                               , a^2 + b^2 == c^2]
```

Comment: Related: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1201.2145.pdf

Comment: @liliscent  I need a function that does it for any number, but that is efficient enough to reach that number in a short time interval (25 seconds-50 seconds)

Comment: @liliscent   I understand the mathematical concept you want to tell me, but I don't know how to write it in Haskell, I'm just starting.

Comment: @liliscent I need to do a program in Haskell, that for any number n gives you the Pythagorean triples that start with that number, as I said above.  But, my teacher asks me for that large number so that we can do it taking into account the algorithmic complexity and the importance of efficiency in functional programming.

Comment: You’ve edited the question to give a much more reasonable problem (145780150 vs 20^100000). Hopefully you can see that this is much more tractable as it is easier to factorise the smaller number. If you are given an even number, divide by two and factorise/find out the numbers divisors, filter by some conditions and then use the formula from @liliscent’s comment to get `b`, `c`. The problem is a little more difficult to solve if you are given an odd number but I think it can be done. If you can write down a clear precise mathematical description of a solution, people here can help with Haskell

Comment: To get `a = m^2 - n^2` consider that `m^2 - n^2 = (m - n)(m + n)` so you want to factorise a in this case too

Comment: @DanRobertson Then, 
1. I factor the given number into prime numbers.
2.  And, after factoring how do I get m and n?

I just don't quite understand the steps I have to take.

Comment: @liliscent You can explain in another way the algorithm you mentioned earlier, that I didn't quite understand it.

Comment: @liliscent: The problem is more difficult than you show, since you left out the possible common factor of a, b, and c (call it k). The complete formula is a=2kmn, b=k(m^2-n^2), c=k(m^2+n^2). So even a given even number could be b, and if it is a it must be factored into 3 divisors other than 2. You could limit it to m and n relatively prime or to k square-free.

Comment: Please don't add solutions to your question. Instead, move it from your question to a new answer below ([answering your own question is perfectly fine to do on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)). Also, `\`` should only be used to mark inline code or literal commands (and things like that), not the non-code names of languages. So, `ghc` would be fine, since it's a terminal command, but `GHC` or `Haskell` are not really good, since none of them are used at the terminal or in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s what to do as an algorithm. Try converting to Haskell and if you get stuck, edit your question to show where you got.

1. Input `a`
2. Factorise `a` into primes
3. Thereby give a factorisation of `a^2`
4. Because `a^2+b^2=c^2`, we have `a^2=(c-b)(c+b)`
5. For each factorisation of `a^2` as `a^2=xy` with `x<y` but not necessarily primes or `x>1`:

   1. Get `c = (x+y)/2`
   2. Get `b = (y-x)/2`
   3. Output `(a,b,c)`

Ok here is an example for 50:

1. Input `a=50`
2. `50=2*5^2`
3. `50^2=2^2*5^4`
4. Not really a step
5. Factorisations `(x,y)` are: `(1,2500), (2,1250), (4,625), (5,500), (10,250), (20,125), (25,100)` Other factorisations have `x>=y` (equivalent to `x>=a`)
6. Corresponding output (where integer solutions exist): `none, (50,624,626), none, none, (50,120,130), none, none`.

Comment: The hard part is going through all the divisors of `a^2`. If you get stuck then update your question with what you have

Comment: Could you make the algorithm for `pythagoreanTriple 25`?  And I take it like example, please.

Comment: I’ve Updated my answer